# If $S^{2n+1}$ is covering space of $X$, then $X$ is orientable.

Tags: differential-topology, differential-forms

Is there any direct way to prove that $n$-manifold is orientable? In AT we can just calculate $n$'th homology group and check whether it's $\mathbb Z$ or $0$. But I want a geometric method, using differential forms. Thanks!

Comment: Are you intending to do any of your homework yourself or have you posted it all?

Comment: Sorry,I have thought these problems for a long time,but I can't find any idea, so I just have to find help...

Comment: Interesting question, btw (one in the title, I mean).

Answer (score 1):

If you have a nowhere vanishing n-form, then the manifold is orientable.

Comment: But how to construct this n-form?I have an idea:for any deck transformation ,it's free, so degree is 1 ,i.e. keep orientable, then we can construct n-form of X from local n-form of S^(2n+1). Is it right?

Comment: @henry "so degree is 1" -- why not $-1$? (And are you using that sphere is odd, not even dimensional?)

Comment: @ Grigory :Yes ,here I use this condition.